# Next.js (React) - Can't import local typescript file into config file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js

**Situation**

I would like to run some Database code (mongoDB(mongoose)) on server startup / during builds. Considering next js doesn't have any lifecycle hooks that you can hook into in an easy manner, I was trying to perform the database actions in my webpack (next.config.mjs) configuration. However I ran into some problems with importing local files.

**Current setup**

This is the code of my current next.config.mjs file. (PS. I have also tried the CommonJS way of requiring the needed files, but that also fails with error meessage "module not found".)
None of the lines that import a local typescript file appear to succeed and I have checked the paths multiple times. They always end up with the error message "ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND". Only if a node_module package is imported, it works as expected (the mongoose npm package).

**Code**

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const { EmployeesSchema } = await import("./mongodb_schemas/employee_schema");
import { EmployeesSchema } from "./mongodb_schemas/employee_schema";
import "./util/test"
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    externalDir: true,
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  images: {
    domains: ["*", "**", "www.google.com"],
  },
  webpack: (
    config,
    { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, nextRuntime, webpack }
  ) => {
    if (isServer) {
      console.log(process.cwd());
    }
    return config;
  },
};

export default nextConfig;
```

Anyone got a clue to why this might end up happening / have any possible solutions to the problem? I have also tried with a normal JavaScript file instead of a Typescript file, which also didn't work. I have found some similar asked questions on Stack Overflow but which were all left unanswered.

My guess for the reason why this occurs: during the build of the project, so when "npm run dev" is ran, the next.config.mjs is copied to a different location into the file structure, which means that the relative paths aren't correct anymore and thus the files can't be found.

PS. My apologize if the question is unclear / in an unusual format, it is my first post so not used to it.